# How to check in VBA that "no document is open"

Tags: vba, ms-office

I'm asking this question, because when the document is opened in safe mode, my macro crashes, pointing to this line:

```
strInput = ActiveDocument.Content
```

So, to prevent this error message:

> This command is not available because no document is open. Error code 4248

I want to check whether there are opened documents or not. And if not, then to set some timer and loop until the user changes the mode of the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean the protected mode?

In that case you can handle the [ProtectedViewWindowActivate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836396.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event of the Application class which is fired when any protected view window is activated.

See [Working with Document Protected View Events in Word](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh128817(v=office.14).aspx) for more information.

Comment: The code on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh128817(v=office.14).aspx (the site you referenced) crashes in the latest versions of office. The `Set doc = Word.ActiveDocument` crashes because "no document is open" which is in the OPs question. Perhaps it works in old office 2010?